# Convert numerical date to alphabetical date in bash without date function

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to convert a numerical date to an alphabetical date in BASH without using the date function (legacy BASH environment).

What I am trying to do is have a case statement of each month, set it to a variable (ConvDate) based on the input TestDate and then return it in the OutputDate variable. However, when I test this, it prints the date rearranged without adding the string to it:

Sample in:

```
10/25/18
```

Sample out as of now:

```
25//18
```

Comment: Your tag is `bash`, but your code appears to be `ksh`. Can you confirm what you need help with, and update your question accordingly?

Comment: Oh wow, that's old. :)  You might want to consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help isolate the problem you're having. As it stands, we can't take the code in your question, run it on our own systems (notwithstanding the bash version) and get similar results. It would be helpful if your question stood on its own, without the need for us to invent the rigging to make it go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts about your code:

- in the branches of the case command, you are attempting to **execute the `Jan` command**, when you need to assign that string to a variable.
- you need to parse the datestring *before* the case command, since you clearly need to know the month number first.
- braces are not quotes: be careful with how you quote your variables (i.e. always quote them) -- this will not hurt you here, unless you actually get the input data from the user.
- you are handling the month number as a string here. If, as your script progresses, you start to handle it as a number, be careful that `08` and `09` are invalid octal numbers and bash will be happy to let you know:

  ```
  $ m=08; echo $(($m+1))
  bash: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
  ```

revised

```
TestDate=09/25/18
IFS=/ read m d y <<INPUT
$TestDate
INPUT
case $m in
    01) Mon=Jan ;;
    02) Mon=Feb ;;
    03) Mon=Mar ;;
    04) Mon=Apr ;;
    05) Mon=May ;;
    06) Mon=Jun ;;
    07) Mon=Jul ;;
    08) Mon=Aug ;;
    09) Mon=Sep ;;
    10) Mon=Oct ;;
    11) Mon=Nov ;;
    12) Mon=Dec ;;
esac
OutputDate="$d/$Mon/$y"
echo "$OutputDate"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there.  When you say `case ${ConvDate} in` this means "When `${ConvDate}` is...".  You should replace `${ConvDate}` with what you're actually testing (so characters 0 to 1 of the date string, or `${TestDate:0:2}`), and then inside the case statements do the assignment:

```
ConvDate=Jan
```